# How to access fields of a Union in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am learning the programming language Elm. I want to access a particular field of a union. I am unable to access it. I have searched in the documentation. But I could not find anywhere how to access a particular field of a Union. The code is as follows:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import List exposing (length, filter, map)

type Person 
  = Person { fname: String, lname: String, age: Int}

p1 = Person { fname="ABC", lname="XYZ", age=23 }
p2 = Person { fname="JK", lname="Rowling", age=24 }

-- These are unions with fields

people : List Person
people = [ p1
         , p2
         , Person {fname= "Anakin", lname= "Luke", age= 12}
         ]

main = show [people]
```

I cannot use `p1.name` since `p1` is not a record. How do I access the field `fname` of `p1` or `p2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation on the website is still getting improved, and need some more links between different parts. The documentation you're looking for is [here](http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem#enumerations).

## Case expressions

The relevant part explains that a union type can have different tagged values, so you need a **case-expression** to distinguish the different options:

```
case p1 of
  Person r -> r.fname
```

## Let expressions

Since in your case there is only one option, you can also safely use a deconstruction pattern in a variable assignment:

```
(Person p1Record) = p1
-- now p1Record is defined, and you can use p1Record.fname
```

### Be careful with let expressions

Note that if you use this assignment trick for a union type with multiple tags, you open your program up to runtime crashes. The crash will happen if the value you try to deconstruct is not of the right tag:

```
type Direction
  = Left
  | Right
  | Forward
  | Back

march : Direction -> Boolean
march dir =
  let
    Forward = dir -- contrived example
  in
    True

main =
  show (march Back) -- oops, runtime crash
```

## Final note

Since your union type has only one tag, you may want to consider using a `type alias` instead. It's just a utility to write a nicer name for a type, but you don't have to unwrap it to use the inner type:

```
type alias Person 
  = {fname: String, lname: String, age: Int}

p1 = {fname= "ABC", lname= "XYZ", age= 23}
-- p1.fname is immediately accessible
```

Comment: I like the type alias example. It is most appropriate. I went through the documentation. Tell me if I am correct: 1. Type aliases are a means to create record types, right?  2.  I tried the deconstructing pattern you suggested, Person p1Record = p1. And then tried to use p1Record.name. But it gives me a compilation error.

Comment: Ok, strangely, you need to put parentheses around the pattern match even though it's the only pattern: `(Person p1Record) = p1`. Thanks for following up on that, <del>I'll edit my answer</del><ins>done</ins>.

Comment: Chetan496, to answer your other question: type alias are a general means to give a different name to a type. But if you directly define a type alias for a record, it will also generate a constructor so you don't have to use record syntax: `type alias Rec = { hi: String, ih: Int }` defines the function `Rec : String -> Int -> Rec` as well as the type.

Comment: Thank you Apanatshka for the information. I did not know that type aliases also define a type as well as a function.